# UISearchController UISegmentedControl deselect all items

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol, uisearchcontroller

Is there a way to deselect all item of `UISegmentedControl` in `UISearchController`? I need to deselect some segment if i tap on a already selected segment. So i will enable all options for search. Only what i can do now for that - create segment "All", but i already have 3 segments. I just have no space for more segments (they all are disappear if i add new one). Thanks.

**UPD**

Still can't find way to get access to `UISegmentedControl` of `UISearchController.SearchBar`

Comment: for deselecting use this line [<segmentcontrl> setSelectedSegmentIndex:UISegmentedControlNoSegment]

Comment: @RameshMuthe problem is how i can get reference to UISegmentedControl?